# Object's associated collection always sums to 0 during validation (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I am recording financial `Interactions`, modelled as an even number of `LedgerEntries` and each overall `Interaction` must sum out to zero.

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, class_name: 'LedgerEntry'

  validate :entries_must_sum_to_zero

  def balance
    credit = self.entries.sum(:credit)
    debit = self.entries.sum(:debit)
    return credit - debit
  end

  protected

  def entries_must_sum_to_zero
    if self.entries.count.odd?
      errors.add(:entries, "There must be an even number of entries.")
    end
    if self.balance != 0
      errors.add(:entries, "Entries must sum to zero.")
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class LedgerEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :credit, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
  validates_numericality_of :debit, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
  belongs_to :interaction

  validate :one_of_credit_or_debit

  protected

  def one_of_credit_or_debit
    if self.credit != 0 && self.debit != 0
      errors.add(:credit, "You can't assign both a credit and debit to the one entry.")
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I have is that this test never fails.

```
it "should complain if an Interaction's balance is non-zero" do
  d = LedgerEntry.create!(credit: 50.0)
  expect {Interaction.create!(entries: [d])}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
end
```

during the execution of `entries_must_sum_to_zero` `self.entries.count` is always 0 and `self.balance` always returns 0.

How do I force the entries to be taken up before the validation method runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your validation, you're using database operations to do the validation (i.e. `count` and `sum`), but the entries haven't been stored to the database yet and won't be until after the `Interaction` is saved and they can be stored with their foreign key.

However, the `entries` attribute can still be accessed and operated on due to the magic of `ActiveRecord` proxies. You just need to use operations that don't depend on going to the database, such as `length` instead of `count` and `to_a.map(&:<attribute>).inject(&:+)` instead of `sum` as in:

```
  def balance
    credit = self.entries.to_a.map(&:credit).inject(&:+)
    debit = self.entries.to_a.map(&:debit).inject(&:+)
    return credit - debit
  end
```

Comment: In which case I might write a factory method to create and post-validate the objects.

Comment: See updated answer. It was bothering me that there wasn't some way to do this within `ActiveRecord` and after playing with some code, discovered the amazing world of `ActiveRecord` proxies.

Comment: That's cool! I'll try that out as soon as I've had some coffee

Comment: Works perfectly.  And gives me something interesting to read up on over my coffee. Thanks very much.

Comment: Your very welcome. I learned some interesting things investigating it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try testing it like this instead:

```
it "should complain if an Interaction's balance is non-zero" do
  entry = LedgerEntry.new(:credit => 50.0)
  interaction = Interaction.new(:entries => [entry])
  expect {interaction.valid?}.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
end
```